# Group by date then summarize and transpose data

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data set that looks like this:

| Date | hh00 | hh01 | hh02 | hh03 | hh04 | hh05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 | 21 | 0 | 51 | 12 | 65 | 96 |
| 2021-09-01 | 0 | 13 | 12 | 34 | 65 | 34 |
| 2021-09-03 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 61 | 96 |
| 2021-09-03 | 45 | 12 | 51 | 12 | 11 | 0 |
| 2021-09-05 | 10 | 0 | 51 | 98 | 23 | 96 |

Where the date column is the date and the hh columns stand for the hour of observation for each day. So in the first row on 2021-09-01 there is an observation of 21 at 00:00 hours and observation of 0 at 01:00 hours etc.

I'd like transform it get a data set containing the sum of the each column by the date and hour, then organized by the datetime. So it looks like this:

| Date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 00:00 | 21 |
| 2021-09-01 01:00 | 13 |
| 2021-09-01 02:00 | 63 |
| 2021-09-01 03:00 | 36 |
| 2021-09-01 04:00 | 130 |
| 2021-09-01 05:00 | 130 |
| 2021-09-03 00:00 | 57 |
| 2021-09-03 01:00 | 12 |
| 2021-09-03 02:00 | 51 |
| 2021-09-03 03:00 | 13 |
| 2021-09-03 04:00 | 72 |
| 2021-09-03 05:00 | 96 |

Comment: First sum your data by group then pivot, `your_data |> summarize(across(everything(), sum), .by = Date) |> pivot_longer(-Date)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(lubridate) # loaded with tidyverse 2.0.0+
df |>
  pivot_longer(-Date) |>
  mutate(Date = ymd_h(paste(Date, parse_number(name)))) |>
  summarize(value = sum(value), .by = Date)

   Date                value
   <dttm>              <int>
 1 2021-09-01 00:00:00    21
 2 2021-09-01 01:00:00    13
 3 2021-09-01 02:00:00    63
 4 2021-09-01 03:00:00    46
 5 2021-09-01 04:00:00   130
 6 2021-09-01 05:00:00   130
 7 2021-09-03 00:00:00    57
 8 2021-09-03 01:00:00    12
 9 2021-09-03 02:00:00    51
10 2021-09-03 03:00:00    13
11 2021-09-03 04:00:00    72
12 2021-09-03 05:00:00    96
13 2021-09-05 00:00:00    10
14 2021-09-05 01:00:00     0
15 2021-09-05 02:00:00    51
16 2021-09-05 03:00:00    98
17 2021-09-05 04:00:00    23
18 2021-09-05 05:00:00    96
```

Comment: lubridate is included in tidyverse fyi :-)